# Upgraded to Android Studio 1.5.0, then 1.5.1 and can no longer create a project

Tags: android-studio

I'm doing a bit of Android dev on the side, so I'm no gradle expert. Just trying to create a project for Android 4.0.3+. This used to work before upgrading to Studio 1.5. Any ideas how to get this setup so can make projects again? I have no idea what appcompat-v7.15+ is or what to install so it can find it.

[image: SDK]

[image: gradle error]

[image: gradle file]

Comment: Try changing the `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`

Comment: use the latest appcompat which in your device.

Comment: Updated the appcompat to 23.1.1. Now building gives me a whole lot of No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android.textAlignment', etc., etc.

Comment: A made a copy of a working project, will use that until the people fix this.

Comment: When using appcompat 23.1.1, be sure to change the compileSdkVersion to 23 as well.

Comment: also had to install the SDK 23 (which is for Android 6 apparently) and seems like I can finally build - thanks all

Comment: also had to delete the following from the build.gradle file:                     android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
} 
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}